# Empty Binary List with pattern matching

Tags: erlang

I'm trying to parse a binary file and when it comes to returning numbers packed in little endian into 16 bits, I am hoping that this would work:

```
foo(Bin, Bits) when is_binary(Bin) ->
    <<A, B, C, D, _Rest>> = Bin,
    (bar(<<A, B>>, Bits) =/= 0) and (bar(<<C, D>>, Bits) =/= 0).

bar(<<N:16/little-unsigned-integer>>, Bits) ->
    binary:at(Bits, N).
```

Unfortunately, the matcher doesn't work when Bin is 4 bytes or less. Is there a better way to make it so the rest can be empty? If I could avoid testing binary length in the caller, the better.

Comment: What would match `C` or `D` if the input is less than 4 bytes long?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
foo(<<A:16/little-unsigned-integer,B:16/little-unsigned-integer,_Rest/binary>>, Bits) ->
    (binary:at(Bits, A) =/= 0) and (binary:at(Bits, B) =/= 0).
```

This will not work with a binary which is less than 4 bytes long. What is supposed to happen in that case?

N.B. `binary:at/2` works on *binaries* not bitstrings and the offset is in bytes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is what I needed to get me unstuck. Grokking the binary stuff in Erlang is very rewarding. The function will never be called with less than 4 bytes so this works fine.